In how many ways can a black king get checkmated by 2 rooks?
Given an nxn chessboard, how many times can a black king get checkmated by 2 rooks (occassionally with the help of a white king)? Is there a mathematical formula that can be brought up?
How many states of the board exists in such a way that the king is in mate. Say like a case of a lawn mower mate, it exists (n-2) x 2 positions for the rooks where it mates the black king, and it exists (n^2 - 2n) positions for the white king to not obstruct the mate. Different positions for a piece is a different state.

Hi, I don't understand how many times can it get checkmated because checkmate is supposed to end the game. Do you mean how many moves can it take or how many different configurations/ways to get checkmated, or something else (maybe if you define what happens after checkmate)?

@alices_and_bobs Hello thank you for your reply, i meant how many states of the board exists in such a way that the king is in mate. Say like a case of a lawn mower mate, it exists (n-2) positions for the rooks where it mates the black king, and it exists (n^2 - 2n) positions for the white king to not obstruct the mate. Different positions for a piece is a different state.

Please add your clarification in comment in the body of the question.

@Evargalo will do thank you

at OP: Is legality an issue? Ka6 Ra7 Rb7 - Ka8 is mate but illegal (no last move). Kc8 Rb7 Rb8 - Ka8 is legal, though (last move a promo to R).

@HaukeReddmann no illegal moves are not allowed

@tendtendonintendo: ACK. You surely mean "illegal positions", since there are no moves involved. (Also suggestion: Ask for the "number of mate positions with ...".)

I am changing this to a community answer because the task is too daunting for me alone. Whoever can contribute, please do !
Answer in progress :
Assuming n>=5

bK not on the edge

When the bK is not on the edge, all three white pieces must take part in the mating pattern. For example :
[FEN "8/7R/1R2k3/8/4K3/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"]

For that pattern the wK must be in opposition to the bK, so it has 4 possible spots if the bK is two squares away from any edge (e.g on c3, (n-4)² possibilities), 3 if the bK is one file away from exactly one edge (e.g. on b3, 4(n-4) possibilities), 2 if the bK is one square diagonally from the corner (e.g. b2, 4 possibilities)
The rooks must then be on two adjacent lines (files or rows), one checking and one taking three escaping squares. There are n-3 possibilities for each rook that are out of reach from the bK, plus 2 positions were they are near the king but protect each other.
So the number of mating positions with the bK not on the edge and the wK in opposition is:
(4x(n-4)^2+3x4x(n-4)+2x4)x((n-3)^2+2) = 4 n^4 - 44 n^3 + 188 n^2 - 364 n + 264
But the wK can also be one knight move away from the bK if the rooks cover one diagonal escape, e.g. :
[FEN "8/3R4/3Rk3/8/5K2/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"]

Such a position is uniquely determined by the kings' positions, and there are 8(n-4)² + 6x8 + 4x2 = 8(n²-8n+23) of them.
Finally, the number of mating positions with the bK not on the edge is:
4 n^4 - 44 n^3 + 196 n^2 - 380 n + 310

bK on the edge but not in the corner

Mate by 2 rooks
Mate by K+R
Mate by 3 pieces

bK in the corner

A. With a double check.
Only possible with a rook-promotion discovery check, e.g.
[FEN "kR6/2K5/8/8/R7/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"]

2 possibilities for the wK, 6 for the vertically-checking rook, hence a grant total of 12 such positions.
B. With a single check, wK involved

For your To-Do-List: Illegal positions are the examples given in my comment, Ra1 Ra2 - Kb1 and the type (Ke6) Ra8 Rh8 - Ke8. Offhand, I don't see others.

@HaukeReddmann there is also Kc3-Ra8-Rh1 vs Ka1. Your first type includes stuff like Ka2 Ra3 Rb3 vs Ka4.
